# Configure keycloak on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, keycloak

I have a keycloak settings and a Laravel app, I make all the configuration but I can't consume my api metod I don't know what I'm doing wrong
this is my configuration in laravel proyect
[image: Configuration]

Error in postman
[image: Postman Error]

I create a .htaccess file with this:
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

And I put on xampp conf the same

I'm running this on a windows pc, my php ver: 7.4.28

I try token on body, url, oauth in postman all send me to the login route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token was decoded, I do a undecode64 and all works fine.